# Clone yourself!

Tags: code-golf, quine, file-system

You are to create a program that creates exact clones of itself infinitely until stopped. Whatever is in the original program must be in the clones. In other words, the clones and original program are the same in every way except for that the clones don't have to be in the same type of file as the source code (they can be text files).

**Example:**

If my original program is:

```
for i in range(0, 10):
     print i
```

the clone must also  be:

```
for i in range(0, 10):
     print i
```

**Rules and Clarifications:**

- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default/5337#5337) are forbidden
- The clones must be the exact copy of the original
- The clones must be readable files that can be run if put inside the correct interpreter
- The program can read its own source code
- All clones must be separate files
- Printing your program out is not allowed
- File names count into the number of bytes
- The clones don't have to be in the same directory as the source file nor share the same file name
- At least 1000 clones should be able to be created

**Winning:**

Least bytes wins!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), <s>19</s> <s>17</s> 9 bytes

```sh
#!/bin/zsh
<$0>$$;$0
```

Per [consensus on meta](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5637/12012), the shebang is excluded from the byte count.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/zsh#S03OyFdQV1bUT8rM068qzvhvo2Jgp6JirWLwX12hRiEjNTFFQTdZQddIQcFOITknPy@VKzkjNz9FQbsCytXTh9Bp@UUKaQqZeQpa1gop@VycBUWZeSVpCkpunj6ufo6@rlYxearFMXm6IBCT5@zvF@LqFxKMKqqkoKSSBiI0bFTSNJW4UoAG/wcA)

Note that TIO's forkbomb protection will kill the process after 113 files have been generated. It can easily generate 1000 files on a system without such conservative resource limits.

Comment: I like ``yes `<$0`|split -1`` a lot better, but that doubles the byte count...

Comment: Too bad the in-out redirection like that does not work  well in _bash_  :(
For one moment, I naïvely thought to have outgolfed you :)

Answer (score 4):

### Batch, 32 bytes

```
set/an=%1+1
copy %0 %n%
%0 %n%
```

Not using `@` because there's no restriction on STDOUT. `%1` defaults to the empty string, so `n` becomes `1` the first time and increments on every pass. Alternatively, this might work for 28 bytes, but I have no idea how random `%random%` actually is when used like this:

```
copy %0 %random%%random%
%0
```

Comment: IIRC `%random%` is based off the current time and can generate anything from 0 to something slightly above 32,000.

Comment: To clarify, `%random%` is a variable that, when accessed, yields a random number as @user2428118 mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

## Bash, <del>25</del>, <del>16</del>, <del>12</del>, 11 bytes

EDITS:

- Removed the newline (-1 byte), Added "Try It Online". Thanks @Dennis !
- Use background job PID `$!` as the filename (will be reused every ~32k files, but that is now allowed), -4 bytes

**Golfed**

```
#!/bin/bash
$0&cp $0 $!
```

**Explained**

Re-spawns itself as a background job with &, before doing a copy, so each iteration will run under its own PID.

Uses the last job PID as the filename.

This can run infinitely (or until stopped) but will be reusing clone filenames approx. every ~32k iterations.

Could be a bit nasty to kill, but AFAIK is not against the rules.

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#VY5BS8NAEIXP7q943W5tq6QpelMRRCIIGg/2mEuyO@kG42zY3agH/3tMaBWcw8A83nx8pK3Dcj5Lq4bTqgx2UNtT3UFtoWbDEt@wVBokGskFbqFbxySEtu/O4PzreG/SYx5aog6XmCNo33QR2nFsuKeA6OB7RsOIllCV@m3vXc9GiM43HGvIRTjgAmz5MVaIGHti8mUksyk4maZgCbVqwyj2OTq1ayFq51FP4LNrGCdOfnkPj09ZfvecXRW8CH/v9y/5Lst3r/9TCanqaa1uVL2Wwoweww8)

Comment: Do you have a testing place where I can try this out for myself?

Comment: @PythonMaster, I will normally use Tutorial Point's online testbed, but it does not have uuid installed, and does not like the script doing so much IO.

Comment: TIO doesn't have a problem with I/O. Also, you don't need the newline after `&`. https://tio.run/nexus/bash#VY5BS8NAEIXP7q943W5tq6QpelMRRCIIGg/2mEuyO@kG42zY3agH/3tMaBWcw8A83nx8pK3Dcj5Lq4bTqgx2UNtT3UFtoWbDEt@wVBokGskFbqFbxySEtu/O4PzreG/SYx5aog6XmCNo33QR2nFsuKeA6OB7RsOIllCV@m3vXc9GiM43HGvIRTjgAmz5MVaIGHti8mUksyk4maZgCbVqwyj2OTq1ayFq51FP4LNrGCdOfnkPj09ZfvecXRW8CH/v9y/5Lst3r/9TCanqaa1uVL2Wwoweww8

Answer (score 3):

### Ruby, <s>78 bytes</s>, <s>77</s> 43 + 4 (filename: a.rb) = 47 bytes

- Version 1.2

43 bytes + name / Thanks to @Alexis
So much shorter!!!

```
loop{File.write "#{$.+=1}",open("a.rb",?r)}
```

that's about as golfed as I think it's going to get

- Version 1.1

73 bytes + name / Thanks to @Alexis Anderson

```
i=0
loop do
File.open("#{i}",?w){|b|b.puts File.read("a.rb",?r)}
i+=1
end
```

- Version 1.0

74 bytes + name

```
i=0
loop do
File.open("#{i}","w") do{|b|b.puts File.read("a.rb")}
i+=1
end
```

This is my first Ruby answer so all inprovements are welcome.

Comment: kernel open forwards to file open, you should be able to omit the File. altogether. ?w in place of "w". I think the do on the File.open is useless, since you have the curly braces.

Comment: open('a.rb',?r) in place of File.read('a.rb')

Comment: ?w is a character w. A string in it's own right. ?w == 'w'. so you don't need the quotes in "?w"

Comment: i=0
loop do
File.write "#{i}",open("a.rb",?r)
i+=1
end

Comment: actually, you can also use curly braces for the loop method too

Comment: loop{File.write "#{$.+=1}",open("a.rb",?r)}
that's about as golfed as I think it's going to get

Comment: Which version of Ruby? In latest 2.4.0 [`Kernel#open`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-open) returns an `IO` object, resulting things like “#<File:0x0055b7ad129bd8>” in the clones.

Comment: You can omit the space between `write` and `"`. Also, is it really necessary to have `"a.rb"` instead of `"a"` or, say, `$/` (which, hilariously, would create a file whose name is a newline, but hey, it works!)?

Answer (score 2):

## sh, 24 bytes

```
yes cp $0 '`uuid`'|sh -s
```

Answer (score 2):

## C#, <s>104</s> 102 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to berkeleybross

```
namespace System.IO{class a{static void Main(){int i=0;while(1>0){i++;File.Copy("c{i}.cs");}}}}
```

No, it's not the shortest. But it's C#. What did you expect?

Comment: You don't need a namespace so you can fully qualify the `File.Copy`. Changing to a for loop so you can inline the int declaration and remove the `1>0` part. And pre increment the `i` in the `File.Copy` statement, that gives you 86 bytes I believe: `class P{static void Main(){for(int i=0;;)System.IO.File.Copy("c.cs","c"+ ++i+".cs");}}`

Comment: Actually this won't work because `c.cs` won't be in the output directory and has to be copied there manually. How does this work?

Comment: Dont forget about string interpolation `$"c{++i}.cs"` is 2 bytes shorter than `"c"+ ++i+".cs"`

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2, 54 bytes

```
from shutil import*
a=__file__
while`copy(a,a*2)`:a*=2
```

Comment: Don't you have to `import sys`?

Comment: @SamuelShifterovich I would have had. I'm not sure how that edit survived as the byte count I was using was for the program now shown

Answer (score 1):

## Processing, 55 + 5 (name of file) = 60 bytes

<sup>I don't know if the filename counts as extra bytes</sup>

```java
for(int i=0;;)saveStrings(i+++"",loadStrings("a.pde"));
```

Pretty much a series of builtins all chained together

#### Explanation

```java
for(int i=0;;)           //A complex piece of code that cannot be explained in words alone
saveStrings(             //Save param2 (String[]) into file param1 (String)
 i+++"",                 // filename: the int i (and then is incremented)
 loadStrings("a.pde")    // content: load the content of file a.pde as a String[]
);
```

Comment: That "complex code" is smiling

Answer (score 1):

## ForceLang + [the ForceLang-JS module](https://github.com/SuperJedi224/ForceLang-JS), 162 bytes

```
set j require njs
j var a=function(){for(;;){var p=new java.io.PrintStream(Math.random()+".txt");p.println("set j require njs");p.print("j var a="+a+";a()")}};a()
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>91</s> 60 bytes

Saved 31 bytes thanks to manatwork

```
<?for(;;)file_put_contents(++$i,file_get_contents("f.php"));
```

Usage: `$ php f.php` clones `f.php` and its code reproducing infinitely itself in filenames like `1`, `2`, `3`...  until timeout.

**Previous version:**

```
<?for($i=0;;$i++)$p=fwrite(fopen("$i.php","w"),fread(fopen($f="f.php","r"),filesize($f)));
```

Usage: `$ php f.php` clones `f.php` and its code reproducing infinitely itself like `f1.php`, `f2.php`, `f3.php` ... `f(n).php` until timeout.

Comment: As the clone file name can be anything, why not use just numbers without extension? `<?for(;;)file_put_contents(++$i,file_get_contents("f.php"));`

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 41 bytes

```
For[a=0,1>0,$Input~CopyFile~ToString@a++]
```

Full program. Copies its own source file into `0`, `1`, `2`, etc. in the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

***Python 2, 61 bytes (unix) 65 (cross-platform)***

**Unix** - *61 bytes*

```
import os;i=1
while os.popen('cp %s %i.py'%(__file__,i)):i+=1
```

On unix cp is the systems copy-file - command. Using the console via **popen** allows me to copy the file by cp. new files will spawn in old-files directory.

**CrossPlatform** - *65 bytes*

```
i=0
while 1:i+=1;open('%i.py'%i,'w').write(open(__file__).read())
```

This works, as **open** on default allows reading.

**Funfact:** replace `1:i+=1` with `i:i-=1` and it will stop at i copies.

Other than that, I see no way of making it shorter than @muddyfish did it.

Answer (score 0):

### awk, 29 (21) bytes,

```
{while(close(i++)||1)print>i}
```

awk is not really the tool for this as it requires `close()` when running indefinitely. Otherwise all it produces are empty files.

If the clone count had a limit, for example 5:

```
{while(++i<5)print>i}
```

the program would be 21 bytes.

Paste the program to a file `a` and run:

```
$ awk -f a a
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 69 bytes

```python
a=open(__file__).read()
i=0
while 1:i+=1;open(`i`+'.py','w').write(a)
```

I tried using `a` for the file name, but (unsurprisingly) Windows does not like files named `a=open(__file__).read()\ni=0\nwhile 1:i+=1;open(`i`+'.py','w').write(a)`. I also tried this:

```python
a=open(__file__).read()
i=''
while 1:i+='.py';open(i,'w').write(a)
```

However it gives me this error:

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/codeGolfCopy.py", line 3, in <module>
    while 1:i+='.py';open(i,'w').write(a)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py.py'
```

It creates 83 files, but that is not even close to the needed 1000.

If you would like to remove these files, you can use this:

```python
import os;i = 1
while 1:os.remove(`i`+'.py');i+=1
```